# How is this method/function called twice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

I am simply sending some data to database directly through code just for testing my database connection stuff. So timing am using GET method instead of POST. 
Here, is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const db = require('../config/database');
const Gig = require('../models/Gig');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const favicon = require('express-favicon');

next();
//Get the gig list
router.get('/', (req, res) => 
    Gig.findAll()
      .then(gigs => {
          console.log(gigs);
          console.log('Looks like no error!!!!');
          res.sendStatus(200);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('ERROR in routes/gigs.js: >> '+err)));

//Add data to database
router.get('/add', (req, res, next) => {
    const data = {
        title: 'Full Stack Developer',
        technologies: 'Node.js, React.js, MongoDB, PostgreSQL, Android, iOS, Wed Development',
        budget: '$5000',
        description: 'Since established in 1995, Bluebird Inc. has developed constantly together with our partners as the leading provider of the mobile computer.'+
        'We have always released innovative products timely to market that meet the expanding needs of our customers,'+
        'which is the essential factor to success in a mobile computing business',
        contact_email: 'hr@comapany.com'
    }

    let { title, technologies, budget, description, contact_email } = data;

    //To insert data
    Gig.create({
        title,
        technologies,
        budget,
        description,
        contact_email
    })
    .then(gig => {
        console.log(gig);
        res.redirect('/gigs');
        res.send();
        return next();
    }) 
    .catch(err => console.log('ERROR while inserting in routes/gigs.js: >> '+err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

The problem is the above function is getting executed twice. I have no idea how to stop it or end the function once it has sent the data to db.

More Code:

```
const express = require('express');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const db = require('./config/database');

db.authenticate()
  .then(() => console.log('Database Connected...'))
  .catch(err => console.log('ERROR:>>  '+err));

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('INDEX'));

//Get routes
app.use('/gigs', require('./routes/gigs'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

Comment: If the route is getting hit twice, then we need more info about how you're calling the route?  Also, you redirect to `'/gigs'` when done.  What does that route do?

Comment: Please `edit ` your code to provide a [Mininum Reproducible Example](https://StackOverflow.com/help). This looks like an awfully lot of code to sort through, when a more concise example would suffice. It'll be more efficient & less daunting for volunteers. Also revisit [How to ask](https://StackOverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and `edit` accordingly. Specifically, avoid help/please/exasperation/shouting in the problem description of your posts, as it's distracting, and does not encourage volunteers to choose your question over others. Everyone here is either asking for help, or providing it

Comment: You can look at your code above, why you have to add `next()` in three and the second thing is, try to comment your favicon.